# Base for refrigerator wine shelf

Tags: refrigerator, carpentry, fitting

I have a wine refrigerator that has shelves for wine bottles - image on this question.

I want to use this refrigerator and its shelves as a regular refrigerator. So I need to put something on the shelf to make it flat so it can hold anything. The inner (usable) part of this shelf is 23" x 17".

At its simplest I think could have some 1/4" plywood cut to those dimensions and simply put them on top.

However this doesn't feel like the correct solution to me. How would I best convert these shelves to a flat surface that can hold any shaped item like a regular refrigerator?

[image: wine shelf]

Comment: you answered  your own question .... use flat material on top of the existing shelves .... as for which material is best, then that is an opinion based question, which is frowned upon at this site

Comment: There are multiple DIY solutions to all problems. All of them are opinion based and situation based. For example a perfect solution in a dry climate might be a terrible solution in a humid climate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an aluminum baking sheet pan? They come in sizes VERY close to what you want and are easily cleaned.

Example of a close size:
[https://www.amazon.com/Winware-ALXP-1622-16-Inch-22-Inch-Aluminum/dp/B001CIEJQU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001CIEJQU)

Answer (score 1):

Tempered glass (might be costly, might not; but a good and common solution seen in fridges, easy to clean, won't harbor mold, etc.)

Plastic would work but will eventually get scratched up somewhat, but is also a common refrigerator interior suface.

Wire mesh (fairly heavy, stiff) works and permits airflow. Stainless steel or powder-coated to prevent corrosion. Again, a common shelf material in this application.

Have you verified that the "wine fridge" will actually operate properly at the temperature range you require? many are optimized for "cellar temperatures" in the mid-50's F (10 C) and don't do well running at normal refrigerator temperatures in the lower 30's (1-3 C)

Comment: Yes this refrigerator has a split level with independent temperature controls and we've tested this. We're currently using it for its future purpose but struggling to get anything to balance on those shelves.

Comment: Wire cooling racks might be easily acquired form for wire mesh. They’ll allow airflow, and you could zip tie the corners to wine rack.

Answer (score 1):

A glass rectangle tray from a microwave might fit. If the door of the fridge is made of glass then it will be quite inefficient, though pretty.